# Creating a python string to be passed as anSQL Expresion(forqgsExpression) from a dict

Tags: pyqgis, sql, python-2.7

Let's say I have the following dictionary:

> foodict = {'a': ['a1','a2'], 'b':['b1','b2'], c:['c1']}

I want to generate the following python string that will be passed as an SQL expression:

```
'"a" = 'a1' AND "b" = 'b1' AND "c" = 'c1' OR "a" = 'a1' AND "b" = 'b2' AND "c" = 'c1' OR "a" = 'a2' AND "b" = 'b1' AND "c" = 'c1' OR "a" = 'a2' AND "b" = 'b2' AND "c" = 'c1''
```

Except the opening and closing quotes, the single/double quotes matters since it is intended as an sql expression being passed to pyqgis.

Example :

```
def extract_by_field_category(inputData, selectionDict, outputData):
lyr = QgsVectorLayer(shp_path,'lyr','ogr') 
selection = lyr.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(SQLEXPRESSION))
```

The dict is an hardcoded parameter in a function call, any suggestion on how to improve it is welcome to. The idea of a dict as argument /parameter seems convenient to reduce the typing needed in the function call.

Comment: I would suggest asking this on [CodeReview:SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as you seem to asking for a way to improve some Python/SQL code =)